# Wordpress Not show image in post

Tags: php, wordpress, image, custom-fields

I have Custom Field (Single image). 
I return Object Image.
My code is:

```
$post_single_image = get_post_field( 'single_image', $post_id );
<?php if($post_single_image!=''): ?>
<div class="art-image-sing" >
     <?php echo do_shortcode($post_single_image); ?> 
</div>
```

But wp returns me id image. 
I tried to change url image, but wp return id image

How can I get anything except the image id?

Comment: In admin panel, in custom fields. Custom fields "single_image" is type "Image Object", but it does not return an image as an object, and returns the id of the image

Comment: Then you need to add a function to make the id spit out an image!!

Comment: thx, it is a way out. Use : wp_get_attachment_image()

Answer (score 0):

You must use the code like this

```
$post_single_image = get_post_field( 'single_image', $post_id );
<?php if($post_single_image!=''): ?>
<div class="art-image-sing" >
     <?php echo do_shortcode([$post_single_image]); ?> 
</div>
```

do_shortcode must be mentioned inside do_shortcode([$post_single_image])